# InpsectorView in Outlook is not updating the contact after updating the contact through my Applications when I am using add-ins enabled, why the cah

Tags: view, microsoft-graph-api, contacts, inspector, outlook-2016

Please guide me why in  outlook  contacts module is not updating  contact in Inspector view
[image]

[image]

Comment: My add-ins enabled than its not updating

Comment: What code do you use for updating contacts in Outlook?